# Text separated by \n doesn't display text in new line in GridView cell in .Net windows

Tags: winforms, datagridview

[image]

Text separated by \n doesn't display text in new line in GridView cell in .Net windows.I have to show account detail in grid and since account can have multiple titles, I need to to show Title in new line in the same cell. Please look at the attached image for detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
"Title1" & cbCrLf & "Title2" & vbCrLf & "Title3"
```

And you should set DataGridViewTextBoxColumn DefaultCellStyle **WrapMode** to true.

Comment: string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, cellValues)